# Create alpha UIView with an UIlabel in front of it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

i would like make an UIView, with an alpha and with a label.

[image]

but i want the UILabel in front of all like this:

[image]

How to do it?

Here the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

  UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 20)];
  lbl.text = @"AAAAAA";
  lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

  UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 210, 230, 50)];
  v.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  v.alpha = 0.5;
  [v addSubview:lbl];

  [self.view addSubview:v];

}
```

The green view is with alpha 0.5... like the text and this is wrong!!!

thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of setting the alpha of the whole view, just set the background color to a color with transparency.

So change this:

```
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
v.alpha = 0.5;
```

To this:

```
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
```

Comment: @Paska when you set the alpha of the whole view the Label is part of that view and so it's alpha is also set.  When you just set the alpha of the background color of the view then the label is unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the built in colors, see colorWithAlphaComponent:

```
accessoryView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the XCode 4 Interface Builder you can achieve this by clicking on the Background property of a view, clicking on "Other", and choosing the color and the opacity values in the color picker that appears.